# Visual Studio Deployment to Azure and detecting the changes

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Each time I'm deploying to Azure from Visual Studio using WebDeploy if I'm the last one deployed it before it will be fast -seems like it will detect the changes- while if I'm not the last one it will be slow and uploading everything.

I experienced this behaviour for long time and now I need to understand what is behind this.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: If another user deploy the project and then I deploy it it will be a slow deployment for me. If I deploy again it will be a quick one. If I'm not wrong the package's dlls  will not get publish this time.